# Empty rows are left after deletion of a row

Tags: c++, qt

If I remove row via model which isn't connected via proxy to a view then removal is correct. As soon as I plug proxy model the contents of removed rows is deleted but rows stay. Any idea why, and how to fix it?
The strangest thing is that first time this works as it's intended only when I try to remove second row, this happens. In my proxy model the data fnc is just a wrapper:

```
QVariant File_List_Proxy::data(const QModelIndex &proxyIndex, int role) const
{
    qDebug() << "Proxy::data index: " << proxyIndex;
    //qDebug() << "Model::data index data: " <<index.data();
   return sourceModel()->data(mapFromSource(proxyIndex),role);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar behaviour on insert. Empty row and only for second time.

If your view isSortingEnabled() is true, turn it off, before you edit model, remove or add something. 
Weird things might happen otherwise, if you refer some coordinates in a model, that might became incorrect suddenly.

Comment: don't have any fnc called isSortingEnabled.

Comment: bool {QTableView|TableView}::isSortingEnabled () const. I meant this function. It is placed in your view class and do it's job when one changes some data in DisplayRole.